# How can I listen to broadcast on a specific interface in c linux?

Tags: c, linux, networking, multicast, broadcasting

I'm currently able to listen to a simple broadcast server I wrote (which just broadcasts "hello") just by doing this:

```
int fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
struct sockaddr_in addr;
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
add.sin_family = AF_INET;
add.sin_port = htons(10074);
bind(fd, struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr));

char buf[800];
recvfrom(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, NULL, 0);
```

What I wonder though is, what interface would the above be using? Some sort of default? And how do I change the interface on which I listen for broadcast? I have seen it in multicast by setting `imr_address` and `imr_ifindex` in the `ip_mreqn` struct but I'm not sure if there is an equivalent for broadcast.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the port you *listen* on you just pick a specific address in your `sin_addr` (you're currently leaving it 0 from `memset` rather than explicitly assigning `INADDR_ANY`).  The address should be one of your IP addresses and the interface will be selected automatically from that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to listen on a specific interface identified by *interface name*, you can use [`getifaddrs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) to map the interface name to a set of socket addresses, then bind sockets to each such address.  (In general it may be necessary to bind more than one socket per address; interfaces can have many addresses.)

It's generally better to configure listeners by *address*, though, and let the kernel worry about which address corresponds to which interface.  That way is consistent with other IP-based services and sysadmins are used to it.